# An exercise of Book--Use the Timing class to compare the performance of the Collection class and an ArrayList when adding 1,000,000 integers to each

Tags: c#

this is an exercise in Chapter One of <<Data Structures and Algorithms Using C#>>. Below are the Timing Class and my test class :

```
{
    public class Timing
    {
        TimeSpan duration;

        public Timing()
        {
            duration = new TimeSpan(0);
        }

        public void stopTime()
        {
            duration = Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime;
        }

        public void startTime()
        {
            GC.Collect();
            GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers();
        }

        public TimeSpan Result()
        {
            return duration;
        }
    }


    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
            Collection<int> collection = new Collection<int>();

            {
                Timing timing = new Timing();
                timing.startTime();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    arrayList.Add(i);
                }
                timing.stopTime();
                Console.WriteLine($"arraylist:{timing.Result().TotalSeconds}");
            }


            {
                Timing timing = new Timing();
                timing.startTime();
                for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
                {
                    collection.Add(i);
                }
                timing.stopTime();
                Console.WriteLine($"list:{timing.Result().TotalSeconds}");
            }

            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
}
```

The problem is the order of two for-loop affect the result : the FIRST for-loop always take less time.
[the ArrayList is first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NC287.png)
[the Collectionis first](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RBIOB.png)
I guess GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers() cause this. But I'm so confused after I read MSDN about GC.WaitForPendingFinalizers(). So WHY? Where does I write wrong?

Comment: Don't benchmark that way. Do it properly with https://github.com/dotnet/BenchmarkDotNet .

Comment: Mmm, actually before we get to that - let's take a step back. What _exact_ output are you getting? Since the way you are calculating duration is _very_ weird. The second one will definitely return a larger number - `TotalProcessorTime` is hardly going to _reduce_ over time... If I count from 1 to 1000 and you ask me the number after 10 seconds and then after 20 then the second number will be higher. But that doesn't tell  you anything useful...

Comment: Agree with Mjwills, `Process.GetCurrentProcess().TotalProcessorTime` Is not the proper way to stop anything. It just return the total time since the start of the program. You may be interrested in a simple Stopwatch https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0.

Comment: Is that timming class part of the exercise? I notice that you added some `{}` in order to reduce the scope of those loop/test. What about taking them to their own method function? But what is the purpose of the exercice? creating a timing class or testing performance of array list ?

Comment: Thanks!!! Like you say, I use the wrong code, it shouldn't **TotalProcessorTime** but  **Process.GetCurrentProcess().Threads[0].UserProcessorTime.Subtract(startingTime)**. And thank you for your recommend about Benchmark too @mjwills

Answer (score 0):

I will simply drop the `Timing` class and use a [Stopwatch](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stopwatch?view=net-5.0) Class.

With minimal modification of your code : https://dotnetfiddle.net/nMJfdT

```
var sw = new Stopwatch(); 
ArrayList arrayList = new ArrayList();
Collection<int> collection = new Collection<int>();


sw.Restart();
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        arrayList.Add(i);
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"arraylist:{sw.Elapsed}");


sw.Restart();
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000000; i++)
    {
        collection.Add(i);
    }
}
sw.Stop();
Console.WriteLine($"arraylist:{sw.Elapsed}");
```

I moved Start/Stop and Console.WriteLine reporting the enlapsed time out of the curly brace because for redability those will need to get their own Method. Like https://dotnetfiddle.net/SsP1Rn

If you need a Timing class in order to not initialise . start and stop manually you can  wrap it like: https://dotnetfiddle.net/N7bdIt

```
public class Timing
{
  public static Stopwatch TimedIt(Action action)
  {
    var sw = new Stopwatch();
    sw.Start();
    action.Invoke();
    sw.Stop();
    return sw;
  }
}
```

Usage :

```
var timeArrayList = Timing.TimeIt(() => AddingToArrayList(1_000_000));
Console.WriteLine($"ArrayList:{timeArrayList.Elapsed}");

var timeCollection = Timing.TimeIt(() => AddingToCollection(1_000_000));
Console.WriteLine($"Collection:{timeCollection.Elapsed}");
```

Comment: I know StopWatch, but thank you all the same